# Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: Returned value cannot be converted to WebElement: {stacktrace=Backtrace:

Tags: java, selenium, google-chrome, selenium-chromedriver, selenium4

I am getting an error in simple program, earlier it was working fine, now for some reason I am not able to execute it.
I am using selenium 3.0.1
Chrome driver 93.0.4
Please check my code and error below.
It would be appreciated if anyone can help me

My Code:

```
public class MouseOverDemo {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C:\\SeleniumJars\\chromedriver.exe");
        WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
        // JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor)driver;
        //driver.get("http://demo.guru99.com/test/drag_drop.html");
        driver.get("https://jqueryui.com/resizable/");
        Actions action = new Actions(driver);

        WebElement resize = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("body.jquery-ui.page.page-id-43.page-template-default.page-slug-resizable.single-author.singular:nth-child(2) div:nth-child(2) div.clearfix.row:nth-child(3) div.content-right.twelve.columns div:nth-child(1) > iframe.demo-frame:nth-child(5)"));
        driver.switchTo().frame(resize);
        WebElement resize1 = driver.findElement(By.id("resizable"));
        action.moveToElement(resize1, 2500, 2500).build().perform();
        System.out.println("Resize is done");
    
    }
```

Error:

```
Starting ChromeDriver 93.0.4577.63 (ff5c0da2ec0adeaed5550e6c7e98417dac77d98a-refs/branch-heads/4577@{#1135}) on port 40273
Only local connections are allowed.
Please see https://chromedriver.chromium.org/security-considerations for suggestions on keeping ChromeDriver safe.
ChromeDriver was started successfully.
Nov. 11, 2021 3:43:35 P.M. org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake createSession
INFO: Attempting bi-dialect session, assuming Postel's Law holds true on the remote end
Nov. 11, 2021 3:43:36 P.M. org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake createSession
INFO: Falling back to original OSS JSON Wire Protocol.
Nov. 11, 2021 3:43:36 P.M. org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake createSession
INFO: Detected dialect: OSS
Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: Returned value cannot be converted to WebElement: {stacktrace=Backtrace:
    Ordinal0 [0x003CD403+2479107]
    Ordinal0 [0x00367D51+2063697]
    Ordinal0 [0x00271F90+1056656]
    Ordinal0 [0x00291A80+1186432]
    Ordinal0 [0x002B58E7+1333479]
    Ordinal0 [0x002B395A+1325402]
    Ordinal0 [0x002B351D+1324317]
    Ordinal0 [0x00254D3F+937279]
    Ordinal0 [0x00255246+938566]
    Ordinal0 [0x00255521+939297]
    GetHandleVerifier [0x0054F3F6+1531734]
    GetHandleVerifier [0x005FE9AE+2249998]
    GetHandleVerifier [0x004539AB+501003]
    GetHandleVerifier [0x00452A29+497033]
    Ordinal0 [0x0036D11D+2085149]
    Ordinal0 [0x00254ADE+936670]
    Ordinal0 [0x002546C0+935616]
    GetHandleVerifier [0x00625E4C+2410924]
    BaseThreadInitThunk [0x765AFA29+25]
    RtlGetAppContainerNamedObjectPath [0x777A7A9E+286]
    RtlGetAppContainerNamedObjectPath [0x777A7A6E+238]
, error=invalid session id, message=invalid session id}
Build info: version: 'unknown', revision: '1969d75', time: '2016-10-18 09:43:45 -0700'
System info: host: 'DESKTOP-HAH9N6P', ip: '172.16.12.8', os.name: 'Windows 10', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '10.0', java.version: '11.0.11'
Driver info: driver.version: RemoteWebDriver
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.findElement(RemoteWebDriver.java:375)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.findElementByName(RemoteWebDriver.java:449)
    at org.openqa.selenium.By$ByName.findElement(By.java:303)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.findElement(RemoteWebDriver.java:360)
    at demoSelenium.Locators.main(Locators.java:21)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: class com.google.common.collect.Maps$TransformedEntriesMap cannot be cast to class org.openqa.selenium.WebElement (com.google.common.collect.Maps$TransformedEntriesMap and org.openqa.selenium.WebElement are in unnamed module of loader 'app')
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.findElement(RemoteWebDriver.java:373)
     4 more
```

Comment: I would upgrade Selenium to 3.141...  (or Selenium 4 which is at stable release status now) delete all dependencies and add them back in... it's a little odd that you have a version of "unknown" in there...    Also check chromedriver vs chrome browser version.  Major versions should match.  (you've got v93 chromedriver so make sure chrome is also v93)

Comment: Thank you for your response... I will try it

Comment: @RajpreetMatharu Did you get a chance to look into the [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69935397/7429447) I have offered? Can I get a feedback?

Comment: @DebanjanB, yes , I am able to execute my program but getting new error

Comment: SLF4J: Failed to load class "org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder".
SLF4J: Defaulting to no-operation (NOP) logger implementation
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#StaticLoggerBinder for further details.

Comment: _`SLF4J: Failed to load class "org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder"`_ sounds to be a new error all together and you may like to raise a new question with all the relevant details.

Comment: @DebanjanB, ok I will raise a new question..... Thank you for the help

Comment: I think that message is normal... It just means that you haven't implemented logs (which is a new feature of Selenium 4)  nop mode means logging is off... does it prevent  your run?

Comment: @pcalkins Yes its running properly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This error message...

```
Starting ChromeDriver 93.0.4577.63 (ff5c0da2ec0adeaed5550e6c7e98417dac77d98a-refs/branch-heads/4577@{#1135}) on port 40273
Only local connections are allowed.
Please see https://chromedriver.chromium.org/security-considerations for suggestions on keeping ChromeDriver safe.
ChromeDriver was started successfully.
Nov. 11, 2021 3:43:35 P.M. org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake createSession
INFO: Attempting bi-dialect session, assuming Postel's Law holds true on the remote end
Nov. 11, 2021 3:43:36 P.M. org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake createSession
INFO: Falling back to original OSS JSON Wire Protocol.
Nov. 11, 2021 3:43:36 P.M. org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake createSession
INFO: Detected dialect: OSS
Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: Returned value cannot be converted to WebElement: {stacktrace=Backtrace:
    Ordinal0 [0x003CD403+2479107]
```

...implies that the [ChromeDriver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59909654/how-does-chrome-driver-interact-with-chrome-browser/59927747#59927747) was unable to initiate/spawn a new *Google Chrome Browsing Context*.

Your main issue is the **incompatibility** between the version of the binaries you are using. Though you are using one of the recent ChromeDriver *v93.0.4577.63* but [Selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54459701/what-is-selenium-and-what-is-webdriver/54482491#54482491) version is **3.0.1** which is *old* and *ancient*.

---

### Solution

Ensure that:

- *JDK* is upgraded to  current levels [JDK 8u311](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/index.html).
- *Selenium* is upgraded to  current levels [Version 4.0.0](https://www.selenium.dev/downloads/).
- *ChromeDriver* is updated to  current [ChromeDriver v95.0](https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/95.0.4638.69/notes.txt) level.
- *Chrome* is updated to  current *Chrome Version 95.0* level. (as per [ChromeDriver v78.0 release notes](https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/78.0.3904.70/notes.txt))
- Take a *System Reboot*.
- Execute your *@Test* as **non-root** user.
- Always invoke `driver.quit()` within `tearDown(){}` method to close & destroy the *WebDriver* and *Web Client* instances gracefully.